# Upgrading from 12.04 LTS to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade, lightdm, unity-2d

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my VAIO, alongside Windows 7.

I know Ubuntu upgrades won't damage my Windows drive and I'm fine about it, but I've seen people saying 'Unity 2D removal' and 'purge drivers before install' and something like that.

I know that Unity 2D is going to be removed, however, I have GNOME, KDE, Xfce and Unity all in my Ubuntu 12.04. I don't know if there's still a problem, or is the entire `lightdm` going to be removed? (Since I didn't choose `kdm` during KDE install so I'm stuck with `lightdm`).

And what's all the fuss about the graphic driver removal?

Can someone please explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely won't remove LightDM, since that's currently the display manager for Ubuntu. The upgrade shouldn't remove your alternate desktop environments, but if it does, then you simply need to reinstall them again though software center.

Graphics drivers are a little more challenging. You'll need to open System Settings, then click on Software and Updates (near the bottom).

[image: Software and Updates]

Next, you'll want to click on the right-most tab (labeled Additional Drivers), then have a look at what's listed there. If there are any binary drivers selected, you'll see a line at the bottom saying "1 Proprietary Driver is in use." If you see this, you'll want to choose the X.org drivers instead. On my system, with an Nvidia graphics card, I see this initially:

[image: Nvidia Selected]

And after selecting the correct driver, I see this:

[image: X.org driver selected]

After this, you can click on Apply changes at the bottom, then restart your system. After this, you should be good to upgrade to 12.10 without any issues.

Comment: Thanks! But when I opened Additional Drivers (It's one of the items in System Settings but not a tab in Software & Updates), it says *No proprietary drivers are in use in this system.* So does that mean that it's 100% safe to upgrade without doing any changes?

Comment: You should be good to go!